# Scrolling in textareafield of Sencha app is not working when run on iOS

Tags: ios, extjs

I have created a popup having textareafield.Textarea is scrollable when run on browser but it is not scrollable when run on iphone

```
 xtype: 'textareafield',
 clearIcon: false,
 itemId: 'comp',
 scrollable:true
```

Comment: could u post full code.. i have to see parent component to0

Comment: Did you checked this on iPad?